# Inheritance in Ruby

Tags: ruby, oop, inheritance

Everything is an object in Ruby. So if we have a class `Hello` it is an instance of a parent class `Object`.

If I do the following in Ruby:

```
Hello = Class.new
World = Class.new(Hello)
```

Does that translate into the following?

```
class Hello
class World < Hello
```

Since multiple inheritance can't be done in Ruby, the `new` method should take only one parameter?

Comment: Most things in Ruby are objects, but there are plenty of exceptions. Examples include blocks, `if` clauses, operators that are not implemented as methods, loops and variables (themselves, not their values).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Positive to both (except that your latter code is invalid).

Note that your "`Hello` it is an instance of a parent class `Class`." is wrong. `Hello` is an instance of `Class`, but its parent is not `Class`, it's `Object`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no. Yes, because as you wrote, it would end up with the same result (assuming you would add missing `ends`). No, as there is small difference in general case. To define anything within `Class.new`, you need to pass a ruby block, which is carrying, and has a full access to, the context it has been created in. So:

```
value = :hello

Hello = Class.new do
  define_method value do
    value
  end
end

Hello.new.hello #=> :hello
value = :world
Hello.new.hello #=> :world
```

Note that the name of the method did not change. However, the value it returns did. This is not ideal and is the reason why `class Hello` is preferred in most of the cases to avoid doing it by accident (same as `def` keyword being preferred over `define_method`).

This will not work with `class` keyword, as it does not create ruby block:

```
class Hello2
  define_method value do
    value
  end
end

#=> undefined local variable or method `value`
```

One more interesting fact about classes and constants is a behaviour of `name` method:

```
my_variable = Class.new
my_variable.name #=> nil

Hello = my_variable
my_variable.name #=> "Hello"

World = my_variable
my_variable.name #=> "Hello"
```